# Accessing html from another file in play 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using the framework Play 2.0 with Java
I have some html

```
<div>my html</div>
```

in a file test.html

Is there anyway I can access the html in another file (say main.html)?
Maybe through some global variable

I tried to surround my html with

```
@variable{<div>my html</div>}
```

Then access it from main.html using

```
@variable
```

But this didn't work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are basically functions as stated in the link that szegedi mentioned.
I think what you want is called `tags` in Play. Basically you have a file with some HTML: let's say a progress bar:

```
@(progressPercentage : Int) // define input params for this view/function

<div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" style="width: @progressPercentage%;">@progressPercentage%</div>
</div>
```

The file above is called **progress.sacala.html** and save in **views.tags.graphs**

The you can `access` or call this piece of HTML by entering the following in one of your views:

```
@tags.graphs.progress(yourPercentageVar)
```

Of course you can do it without passing any variable, but I thought it would be nice to include the vars as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should try html escaping:

```
@Html(test.content)
```

If that doesn't work, here's the doc, how to use the templating engine for what you want:
[Java template usecases](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaTemplateUseCases)